# preloading a tree / hierarchy from database using NHibernate / C#

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I need to populate some tree hierarchies and traverse them in order to build up a category menu.  Each category can have more than 1 parent.   The problem is how to do this efficiently, and try to avoid the `Select N+1` problem.

Currently, it is implemented by using two tables / entities:

```
Category
--------
ID
Title

CategoryLink
---------
ID
CategoryID
ParentID
```

Ideally, I would use the normal object traversal to go through the nodes, i.e by going through `Category.ChildCategories`, etc.  Is this possible to be done in one SQL statement?  And also, can this be done in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `batch-size` on the `Category.ChildCategories` mapping.  That will cause NHibernate to fetch children in batches of the specified size, not one at a time (which will alleviate the N+1 problem).

If you are using `.hbm` files, you can specify the `batch-size` like this:

```
<bag name="ChildCategories" batch-size="30">
```

or using fluent mapping

```
HasMany(x => x.ChildCategories).KeyColumn("ParentId").BatchSize(30);
```

See the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch) for more info.

**EDIT**

Ok, I believe I understand your requirements.  With the following configuration

```
HasManyToMany<Item>(x => x.ChildCategories)
    .Table("CategoryLink")
    .ParentKeyColumn("ParentId")
    .ChildKeyColumn("CategoryID")
    .BatchSize(100)
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Fetch.Join();
```

you should be able to get the entire hierarchy in one call using the following line.

```
var result = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category)).List();
```

For some reason, retrieving a single category like this

```
var categoryId = 1;
var result = session.Get<Category>(categoryId);
```

results in one call per level in the hierarchy.  I believe this should still significantly reduce the number of calls to the database, but I was not able to get the example above to work with a single call to the database.

Comment: I'm already using batch-size.  However, that only solves it for one level, not for `n` levels.  The tree can be deep say 3, 4 or even more levels.  Ideally I'm looking at 1 query for the whole level.

Comment: Batch size does not exactly produce efficient query plans. It produces tons of singleton lookups. Can be a good trade-off between perf and engineering time though.

Answer (score 0):

This would retrieve all the categories with their children:

```
var result = session.Query<Category>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.ChildCategories)
                    .ToList();
```

The problem is determining what the root categories are. You could either use a flag, or map the inverse collection (`ParentCategories`) and do this:

```
var root = session.Query<Category>()
                  .FetchMany(x => x.ChildCategories)
                  .FetchMany(x => x.ParentCategories)
                  .ToList()
                  .Where(x => !x.ParentCategories.Any());
```

All sorting should be done client-side (i.e. after `ToList`)